# Disabling html button using JavaScript won't POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this Javascript and HTML code for my button:

```js
function lockoutSubmit(button) {
  var oldValue = button.value;

  button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  button.value = '...processing...';

  setTimeout(function(){
    button.value = oldValue;
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }, 3000)
}
```

```html
<button style="margin-right:-160px;" type="submit" name="gen" onclick="lockoutSubmit(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Generate account!</button>
```

The code works fine for disabling the button for 3 seconds but the button is no longer posting to "gen".

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but disabled form elements dont post in general. Also the button value in settimeout could theoretically change until its called in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the innerHTML instead of the value and bind the parameters to the settimeout instead of relying on the context.

Also button value might not be what you think it is:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function _Unlock(){
                var tB = document.getElementById('gen');
                tB.removeAttribute('disabled');
                tB.innerHTML = 'Generate account!';

                localStorage.setItem('Lock', 0);
            }

            function Unlock(){
                var tS = localStorage.getItem('Lock');

                if (tS != '1') _Unlock()
                else{
                    setTimeout(function(e, v){
                        _Unlock()
                    }, 3000)
                }
            }

            function setToLock(){
                localStorage.setItem('Lock', 1);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'Unlock()'>
        <!-- Do you have a form and is it setup correctly? -->
        <form action = '' method = 'post' id = 'myForm' onsubmit = 'setToLock()'>
            <button id = 'gen' type = 'submit' name = 'gen' disabled = 'disabled'>...processing...</button>
        <form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still does not submit it correctly. This is the code its submitting to:
`
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['gen'])){                   
    $f_contents = file("../t.txt");
    $line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
    $data = $line;
`

Comment: Well I dunno what it is supposed to submit, yet if you want it to submit a value set one with the value attribute. The text - label of the button is not the value. Also we need your <form> to provide further assistance. Does your php get any posted values at all?

Comment: To submit values, in this case post, you need to wrap it in a <form> tag with action and method. Do you have that and is the form posted correctly? I added it in my answer.

Comment: Im using this tag: <form method="POST">

Because its not working with JavaScript is there any way to disable the button for X seconds using PHP?

Comment: No, not directly. Did you set the action attribute in your form tag to post to your php file which includes isset($_POST['gen']) or is it the same file?

Comment: Same file. Its just above the form tag.

Comment: I have a logical problem with what you want.. if you post the site on itself then it will reload and process the posted data - thus making the settimeout and the text change on your button redundant. Also on the script you provided, you never actually post the form. I expanded my example.

Comment: So I should put it in its own file and use include once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79774/discussion-between-user3724476-and-lain).